# After adding Typeorm to My project I cannot make postgresql queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, typeorm

Whenver I go to my pgAdmin query console and fire a query then I am not able to query the tables created by TypeOrm

[image: For example this works fine]

But whenever I am adding a where clause it does not allow me to query

[image: Example of my where clause query]

Can someone guide me why can't I query or what mistake am I making here?

Comment: try : select * from `user` u where u.`name`="Hey", I think name is a reserved word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up `"` and `'`. You have to use `"` for identifiers (like tablenames, `"User"`), but normal strings have to be surrounded with `'` (`'Hey'`).

So the correct version of you statement is:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM "User"
WHERE name = 'Hey';
```

Small sidenote: It is mostly seen as bad practice to use upper-case identifiers, as you need to quote them with `"` always. Usually, the tablename would be `user` and you can refer to it using `user` or `User`.